# Retrieve distinct rows after a join

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

I am performing a join between two events as follows. How can I get distinct rows in my final output?

```
let fromdate = "2017-04-26 23:00";

let fileEvents = (Events
| where Timestamp > todatetime(fromdate) 
| project fileId, fileName, Application);

fileEvents | join (Events
    | where Timestamp > todatetime(fromdate) and Data.Size > 1024
    | project fileId) on fileId
| project fileId,Application, fileName;
```

Query output

```
1 , Web , Agreement
1 , Web , Agreement
2 , Api , Contract
2 , Api , Contract
1 , Web , Agreement
2 , Api , Contract
```

I want the output to be

```
1 , Web , Agreement
2 , Api , Contract
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [summarize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference#summarize-operator) operator to summarize by all result columns:

```
let fromdate = "2017-04-26 23:00";

let fileEvents = (Events
| where Timestamp > todatetime(fromdate) 
| project fileId, fileName, Application);

fileEvents
| join (Events
| where Timestamp > todatetime(fromdate) and Data.Size > 1024
| project fileId) on fileId
| summarize by fileId, Application, fileName
```

An equivalent of the above will be:

```
let fromdate = "2017-04-26 23:00";
Events
| where Timestamp > todatetime(fromdate) 
| project fileId, fileName, Application
| join (
    Events
    | where Timestamp > todatetime(fromdate) and Data.Size > 1024
    | project fileId) on fileId
| summarize by fileId, Application, fileName
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But I am getting a Bad argument error when I include some of the columns. Is there a way to overcome that problem? Will it be a problem if some of the columns do not have values in some instances?

Comment: Can you share the error? Empty values should not be an issue

Comment: Here is my complete [code](https://gist.github.com/codingdawg/c8fa3bbf73064bb6a8c7eb895898b29b) .. Added the error message at the bottom. In the code I have commented the problematic code on Line 28.

Comment: Make sure to explicitly cast dynamic values before using them for summarization - same as you've casted 'envId'